# Counting upper-case characters in array with strings

Tags: java, arrays, string

So i'm trying to count the number of upper-case characters in a array with strings. I'm at a brick wall here. If someone could shed some light on my problem that would be fantastic.

I assume the same loop can be done with just Character.isLowerCase(item) as well right?

After this is completed I also have to tell the user the longest string in the array and how many characters the longest string has as well which I really don't know how to do.

Professor really threw a curve ball at us with this one..

So here's my code so far:

```
// Program3.java
// Brandin Yoder
// 2/23/18
// Store strings in an array and tell user number of upper-case and lower-case characters,
// and spaces
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Program3
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   // Set up keyboard.
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   // Input number of strings to store.
   System.out.print("Number of strings to input:  ");
   int nrStrings = keyboard.nextInt();

   // Clear keyboard buffer.
   keyboard.nextLine();

   // Set up array to hold strings.
   String[] strings = new String[nrStrings];

   // Input strings from keyboard.
   System.out.println("\nInput strings:");

   for(int ctr = 0; ctr < nrStrings; ctr++)
   {
     System.out.print("String #" + (ctr+1) + " :");
     strings[ctr] = keyboard.next();
   }

   // Print back strings input.
   System.out.println("\nStrings input:");

   for(int ctr = 0; ctr < nrStrings; ctr++)
   {
     System.out.println("String #" + (ctr+1) + ":  " + strings[ctr]);
   }

   // Set up variables for upper-case, lower-case and white space calculator.
   int UpperNr = 0;
   int LowerNr = 0;
   int Spaces = 0;

   // For loop that determines amount of Upper-Case numbers.
   for(int ctr = 0; ctr < nrStrings; ctr++)
   {
     char item = strings[ctr].charAt(ctr);

     if(Character.isUpperCase(item))
     UpperNr++;
   }

   System.out.println(UpperNr);
 }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: It sounds like an assignment that aims to teach about decomposition of the problem. Consider first a single string.  Can you build a function that gets a single string from reading input?  Can you build a function that counts uppercase in a single string?  Get those working, then this problem with arrays of strings will be easy.

Comment: Before iterating through the last loop create two variables for the maxLength and another for the index of the maxLength element

Comment: BTW, `char item = strings[ctr].charAt(ctr);` is incorrect - you need (based upon this code) a nested `for` loop.  The outer loop will read the Strings and the `inner` loop will read the chars of **that** string

Comment: Scary Wombat, thanks for helping so much. A nested for loops makes perfect sense thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create variables to hold the data that you want to print out at the end. In this case you need to maintain an array that has the number of Uppercases for each string as well as the index and length of the longest string. You have to use a nested for loop to iterate through the array of strings that you have and also the strings themselves in order to check how many Uppercase characters you have. I have modified/commented the last part of your code below.

```
   //array that contains number of uppercase letters in each string
   int[] upperAmount = new int[nrStrings];
   //index of the longest string
   int maxLenIndex = 0; 
   //length of longest string
   int maxLength = 0; 

   //array that iterates through all the strings in the array strings[]
   for(int i = 0; i<strings.length;i++){
     //if the new string is the longest 
     if(strings[i].length() > maxLength){
       //set maxlength to the new length and record index of string
       maxLength = strings[i].length();
       maxLenIndex = i; 
     }
   // For loop that determines amount of Upper-Case numbers.
      for(int ctr = 0; ctr < strings[i].length(); ctr++)
      {
         char item = strings[i].charAt(ctr);
         if(Character.isUpperCase(item))
           UpperNr++;
      }
      //add number of uppercases to upperAmount array indexes will be the same
      upperAmount[i] = UpperNr; 
      //reset upper number
      UpperNr = 0; 
   }

   // Print back strings input.
   System.out.println("\nStrings input:");

   for(int ctr = 0; ctr < nrStrings; ctr++)
   {
     System.out.println("String #" + (ctr+1) + ":  " + strings[ctr]);
     System.out.println("Number of Uppercase Letters: " + upperAmount[ctr]);
   }

   System.out.println("MaxStringLength: " + maxLength);
   System.out.println("Max String: " + strings[maxLenIndex]);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves your problem

```
//after you finish printing the strings
           String strMax="";
           int ctr=0;
           for(String str :strings ){
               strMax = str.length()>strMax.length()?str:strMax;
               if(!str.equals(str.toLowerCase())){
                   for(char c : str.toCharArray()){
                       if(Character.isUpperCase(c))
                           ctr++;
                   }
               }
           }
           System.out.println("Longeset String"+strMax );
           System.out.println("total Upper case chars" +ctr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it neccesarry to input the count of strings? I think you can accept one whole string and convert it into array of chars
`char[] charArray = acceptedString.toCharArray;`
Then go throw all chars, and where `charArray[n] > 64 && charArray[n] < 91` increase your variable to counting UpperCases. Hope you understand) Ask if you have questions.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String inString = keyboard.nextLine();

char[] symbol = inString.toCharArray();

int count =0;

for(int i =0; i < symbol.length; i++){
  if(symbol[i] > 64 && symbol[i] < 91){ //cause every char has its own number in Unicode. 'A' = 65 and 'Z' = 90
    count++;
  }
}

System.out.print(count);
```